# How to GROUP BY based on newly created MAX() column

Tags: sql, group-by, partition

My table:

| Name | ID | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Roger Collins | 904 | 3 |
| Roger John Horspool | 915 | 3 |
| Roger John Shippey | 932 | 3 |
| Roger John Shippey & T.C. Rowell | 5341 | 2 |
| Roger John Shippey & T.C. Rowell | 5341 | 3 |

Due to poor inputting, some people (e.g. R J Shippey & T C Rowell) have more than 1 'status' value.
What I would like to do is do a GROUP BY on this table, but on the MAX value of status.
So the table would look like this:

| Name | ID | Max_Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Roger Collins | 904 | 3 |
| Roger John Horspool | 915 | 3 |
| Roger John Shippey | 932 | 3 |
| Roger John Shippey & T.C. Rowell | 5341 | 3 |

I have managed to make a new column with the Max_Status, like so:

| Name | ID | Status | Max_Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Roger Collins | 904 | 3 | 3 |
| Roger John Horspool | 915 | 3 | 3 |
| Roger John Shippey | 932 | 3 | 3 |
| Roger John Shippey & T.C. Rowell | 5341 | 2 | 3 |
| Roger John Shippey & T.C. Rowell | 5341 | 3 | 3 |

Using this code:

```
SELECT Name, 
        ID,
       Status,  
       MAX(Status) OVER(PARTITION BY Name) AS MaxStatus 

FROM [dbo].[TaskStatus_View]
```

But now I can't do a groupby based on the Max_Status column, because (from what I understand) I am creating it after I am accessing the original database so it just says invalid column name.
So I am unsure on the next step. I have tried to put the Partition line into a subquery, but I can't really grasp this intuitively.

Comment: like this? https://dbfiddle.uk/EuzNeMWZ

Comment: Why do you need a window function at all why not normal aggregation https://dbfiddle.uk/smGdogz9 Or use top 1 per group methods https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group?r=Saves_AllUserSaves

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can use your query as a subquery and perform the grouping

```
SELECT Name,ID,MaxStatus FROM
(
  SELECT Name,ID,Status,MAX(Status) OVER(PARTITION BY Name) AS MaxStatus 
FROM [dbo].[TaskStatus_View]
) t
GROUP BY Name,ID,MaxStatus
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/EuzNeMWZ)

| Name | ID | MaxStatus |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Roger Collins | 904 | 3 |
| Roger John Horspool | 915 | 3 |
| Roger John Shippey | 932 | 3 |
| Roger John Shippey & T.C. Rowell | 5341 | 3 |

Comment: yeah amazing thank you. I was getting confused by where the sub query should go, but I see now it is after the FROM so you can pull data from it. thanks again :)